# replace black by white and white by black in images

Tags: image, python-3.x, opencv, image-processing

I have black and white images (png) as follow :
l want to replace the black background font color into white and the written character in white to black. How to identify color and replace it ?

for that l have thousand of images. It s not possible to manually identify in which image the character is in black and the background is in white and vice versa. all what l need is for every image l check if the character is written in black  if not change the character color to black and the background to white.

**here is a link to my sample of data : https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-QJnh0Uw96lbFVHbVBPclhycFk**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Check the four pixels at the corners. If at least two are black, the image is white. It's quite improbable that a character _touches_ the corners...

Comment: But it may result in a tie as in the above case of inverted V, if it had been cropped by even 2-3 pixels, then there would have been a tie in that case @Miki

Comment: You could manually check the ties... they'll be much less than the original thousands

Comment: I guess, Iterating over all the boundary pixels, and taking the max would suffice most of the cases @Miki

Comment: That would have problems with the second image, where the "0" seems to touch the central parts of the boundaries (but not the corners)

Comment: yes @Miki, actually it s the issue

Comment: can you upload a zip file with all your character images somewhere? :)

Comment: often it should be the color with fewer contour components/fragments, but you'll need additional hints for example if the cropping isn't so nice and the background becomes a single surrounding contour, etc.

Comment: You're expecting people to tell you how to infer if a character is white or black in a general case, yet you provide just 2 examples. So do you want it working for 2 examples or for all of them? If for all, provide the necessary data.

Comment: Your title doesn't correctly summarise your problem - the problem isn't how to invert the colors, it's how to decide whether or not to invert, and if you only give two examples those are the only ones anyone can possibly give you advice on.

Comment: @Micka here is the lik to a sample of my data : https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-QJnh0Uw96lbFVHbVBPclhycFk

Comment: @m3h0w for all of them  l provided the link

Comment: @barny actually it's is about how to decide and then invert .

Comment: OK so change the title of the question

Answer (score 4):

If the white content has the value 255 (if it is a binary mask 1) just subtract your image from 255. In python if your image is **img**:

```
cv2.subtract(255, img)
```

Comment: but l have a thousand of images , l need to identify the black part and white part of each image then change the color. do for it will be all about add 255  and subtract 255. My question is actually how to identify them then apply add 255 or subtract ?

Comment: OpenCV does that ?

Comment: @Micka I guess that the issue here is that you don't know when to invert

Comment: @Miki, yes it is

Answer (score 1):

For the sample you provided, if the image dimensions are >~26 pixels wide, invert.